# C error: incompatible pointer types issue using typedef for int array

Tags: c, error-handling

I am trying to implement a simple function that assigns the values of one array to another, but I keep getting an error

```
program.c:90:14: error: incompatible pointer types passing 'longint_t' (aka 'int [3]') to parameter of type 'longint_t *' (aka 'int (*)[3]'); take the address with & [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

My initial thought behind this is that it should take 2 longint_t values (usually one will be empty or all zeroes, but not always), and another longint_t value and assign all the values of the second array to the first.

in the end, the variable vars should be of the form

```
[ 
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],
.
.
. 26 arrays of [0,0,0]
]
```

Here's my bit of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INTSIZE 3   /* max number of digits per integer value */
#define NVARS   26  /* number of different variables */

typedef int longint_t[INTSIZE];

void do_assign(longint_t *var1, longint_t *var2);
void zero_vars(longint_t vars[]);


/* Main program controls all the action
*/
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    longint_t vars[NVARS];

    zero_vars(vars);
    for (int i=0; i<NVARS; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3;j++){
            //printf("%d",vars[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void
zero_vars(longint_t vars[]) {
    int i;
    longint_t zero = {0};
    for (i=0; i<26; i++) {
      do_assign(vars[i], &zero);
     }

    return;
}

void
do_assign(longint_t *var1, longint_t *var2) {
    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++){
        *var1[i] = *var2[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler error tells you what is wrong. Your function `do_assign(longint_t *var1` needs a pointer to `longint_t` and you give it `longint_t`. My guess is that you want `do_assign(longint_t var1, longint_t var2)`.

Comment: @pptaszni I tried that, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=500; i++)` you might want to increase `INTSIZE` to `501`.

Comment: @Eljay sorry that was an error, I fixed it

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)` you might want to increase `INTSIZE` to `4`, since `i<=3` will access the 4th element.

Comment: This is the very reason why we shouldn't hide arrays (or pointers) behind typedef. You can no longer read or understand your own code - get rid of the typedef.

Comment: `do_assign(vars[i], &zero);` -> `do_assign(&vars[i], &zero);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers to arrays is a niche C topic, which is very confusing due to [array-to-pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/509868).

Your `do_assign` function should assign one array to another (but it's buggy; see below). It receives pointers to the arrays.

Your `zero_vars` function should initialize a 2-D array (array of arrays). It also receives a pointer to an array (this is what the compiler thinks, due to the decay rules). But it gives this pointer a different meaning — it's a pointer to the first element of the array. This array has `NVARS` elements, each one of which is an array of `INTSIZE` integers. Confusing!

In your `zero_vars` implementation, `vars[i]` is an array. However, `do_assign` receives a pointer to an array! So you should take its address:

```
  do_assign(&vars[i], &zero);
```

However, in your `do_assign` implementation, you should dereference your pointers:

```
    (*var1)[i] = (*var2)[i];
```

You dereference the pointer first, and index the result afterwards. Due to operator precedence rules, you should specify the order of these operations, explicitly.

---

You don't need a "pointer to an array" type to implement all this. You can use "pointer to `int`" instead. This way, you avoid an unnecessary and confusing indirection:

```
void
do_assign(int *var1, int *var2) {
    for (int i=0; i<INTSIZE; i++){
        var1[i] = var2[i];
    }
}
```

Due to array decay rules, the following would also work, and do exactly the same:

```
void
do_assign(longint_t var1, longint_t var2) {
    for (int i=0; i<INTSIZE; i++){
        var1[i] = var2[i];
    }
}
```

But I am not sure it's clearer — array `typedef`s are also a rarely-used feature because of the uncertainty and confusion they may introduce.

Comment: Oh I see. 
I have been struggling to understand pointers in C for some time.
This really helped Thank you so much!
My question is would this also work if instead of an array of three 0s  I wanted an array of 500 0s or would that lead to overflow problems?

Comment: If all your dimensions and indices are correct, there will be no overflow. The compiler does exactly the same for 500 as it does for 3. I have just noticed the indices were buggy; edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
do_assign(&vars[i], &zero); // this compile successfully in my device.
```

This function take two pointers as parameters. Thus, you should pass the address instead of the value by using &.

Comment: For some reason though that resolves the previous error, it results in 
var=
02282-145021416
0-6371244-6371248
00-142708......
and so on

Comment: @sun_dance you should provide more detail. what are you expecting the variable var be like ?

Comment: I added more info